# Multilabel model scores better than the same model with binary-labels in scikit-learn

Tags: machine-learning, scipy, scikit-learn, random-forest, multilabel-classification

I have a scikit-learn model, which simplified a bit would look like:

```
clf1 = RandomForestClassifier()
clf1.fit(data_training, non_binary_labels_training)
prediction1 = clf1.predict(data_testing)


clf2 = RandomForestClassifier()
binary_labels = label_binarize(non_binary_labels_training, ["a", "b", "c"])
clf2.fit(data_training, binary_labels)
prediction2 = clf2.predict(data_testing)

f1_score1(non_binary_labels_testing, prediction1))
f1_score2(binary_labels_testing, prediction2))
```

Now, `f1_score1` is always better than `f1_score2`. In other words, the multiclass labels score better than the binary labels (generated from the same multiclass labels). Is there a reason and is this expected?

I have about 70 training and test files and 36 classes (not three like in the example above).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like when you binarize labels, random forest can predict multiple labels at once, while predicting only the most probable label in the initial case. F1 score is sensitive to that.

UPD: I'm wrong. I've tested it and it my case it always returns only one label, but score is still bad.

UPD2: I'm not so wrong as I thought. sum(sum(prediction2)) appears to be lesser than len(prediction), so there should be 0 in some rows.

Comment: To clarify this, if you have a single-output model, it's best NOT to binarise the labels, as doing so might decrease the accuracy of the prediction.